# Creating awk program to add last column of data

Tags: unix

Im attempting to create an awk program to add the last column of data (amount of time a user is connected) while making the formatting still readable (Hours no greater than 24, no mins greater than 60.) However with the first line - it doesn't display a time and ill have to ignore it.

```
jms68988 pts/0 161.6.5.14 Fri Mar 22 08:41 still logged in
jms68988 pts/4 ip143-84.snl.wku Wed Mar 20 10:15 - 11:14 (00:58)
jms68988 pts/0 161.6.5.14 Wed Mar 20 09:59 - 07:44 (1+21:45)
jms68988 pts/0 161.6.5.14 Wed Mar 20 09:18 - 09:30 (00:11)   
jms68988 pts/3 ip143-84.snl.wku Mon Mar 18 10:18 - 11:13 (00:55)   
jms68988 pts/6 ip143-84.snl.wku Fri Mar 15 10:15 - 11:14 (00:59)
jms68988 pts/6 ip143-84.snl.wku Wed Mar 13 10:16 - 11:13 (00:57)   
jms68988 pts/1 161.6.5.14 Wed Mar 13 10:05 - 07:47 (4+21:41)
jms68988 pts/0 161.6.5.14 Fri Jan 25 12:42 - 07:57 (2+19:14)
jms68988 pts/7 ip143-84.snl.wku Fri Jan 25 10:28 - 11:16 (00:47)
jms68988 pts/0 161.6.5.14 Fri Jan 25 08:33 - 08:35 (00:01)
```

could you do such a thing using awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very *much* do something like that in `awk` - There are two basic aspects to consider:

- record selection; and
- record processing.

---

The first (record selection) is done by looking for a specific regex on each line, the code below selects the most likely case for your input data, specifically that the final field matches:

```
(<days>+<hours>:<minutes>)
```

where the `<days>+` is optional, the three fields are numeric, and there are optional spaces after the field. This throws away lines such as the first, where the final field is `in`. Obviously, if your data can take *different* forms, you will need to adjust this.

---

The second (record processing) involves working out the actual time represented by the final field of each record selected. You can do that by breaking apart the string into it's three components, converting them into a common base value (minutes, at 1440 minutes per days and 60 minutes per hour), and accumulating that value across the entire set of selected records.

---

Then, at the end, convert those minutes back into days, hours, and minutes, and output the results.

Here's an `awk` script `prog.awk` which does just that:

```
/\(([0-9]+\+)?[0-9]+:[0-9]+\) *$/ {
    # Split field on ALL puctuation, this puts empty string
    # on either side, so one of:
    #      1        2          3            4          5
    #   <empty> ( <days>  + <hours>   : <minutes> ) <empty>
    #   <empty> ( <hours> : <minutes> ) <empty>
    # Once we know which one it is, we just extract to the
    # correct variables.

    sz = split($NF, tmArray, /[()+:]/)
    if (sz == 5) {
        dd = tmArray[2] + 0
        hh = tmArray[3] + 0
        mm = tmArray[4] + 0
    } else {
        dd = 0
        hh = tmArray[2] + 0
        mm = tmArray[3] + 0
    }

    # Output line for debugging.

    printf "%3dd %3dh %3dm %s\n", dd, hh, mm, $NF

    # Accumulate minutes.

    total += dd * 1440 + hh * 60 + mm
}
END {
    # After all records, convert minutes back to
    # dd/hh/mm and print.

    dd = int(total / 1440)
    left = total % 1440

    hh = int(left / 60)
    mm = left % 60

    printf "=====\n%3dd %3dh %3dm (from %dm)\n", dd, hh, mm, total
}
```

As an aside, if you're concerned about my sanity regarding code like `value = something + 0`, this is just a way to force `awk` to treat a variable as a numeric value rather than a string.

When you run that on your input data `prog.input`, you can see the results:

```
pax> awk -f prog.awk prog.input
  0d   0h  58m (00:58)
  1d  21h  45m (1+21:45)
  0d   0h  11m (00:11)   
  0d   0h  55m (00:55)   
  0d   0h  59m (00:59)
  0d   0h  57m (00:57)   
  4d  21h  41m (4+21:41)
  2d  19h  14m (2+19:14)
  0d   0h  47m (00:47)
  0d   0h   1m (00:01)  
=====
  9d  19h  28m (from 14128m)
```